# Plunger only temporarily resolves shower drain clog

Tags: shower, drain

The water in my shower doesn't drain properly, so I used the plunger and the problem seemed to be solved. However, the next time someone uses the shower it's the same problem again: water doesn't drain, plunger, water drains.

I wonder what the problem is, because the pipe seems to be clean, otherwise the water wouldn't drain as it does (after using the plunger). But why doesn't the water drain the next time? I was wondering if it has something to do with air in the pipe. But even if this were the case, I wouldn't have any idea how to solve the problem. I'm grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't access at the drain, try using drain cleaner or a [drain snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumber%27s_snake). Drain cleaner will dissolve any organic matter and a snake will dislodge any caught hair or other material in the drain.

There may also be a problem with [the venting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drain-waste-vent_system) if none of the solutions are correcting the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I used something like a snake, and I also finally managed to access the drain and clean out everything. I also thought that the venting might be a problem, but up to now everything seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

A slow-draining shower is often caused by hair caught on the crossbar where the screw that holds the strainer attaches. Unscrew the screw in the middle of the strainer and lift out the strainer and the screw. If there's a bunch of hair there, pull it out. (Ewww...).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is that there's no screw on the strainer, it's somehow fixed to the tiles. But if hair was the problem, why would it drain after using a plunger, and why wouldn't it then also drain a day later?

Comment: It's only been 8 years, @MattL., but... If you're plunging by pushing _down_, you're simply forcing the clog further down the drain. You've moved it enough to drain this time, but the next shower, it catches more gloop and clogs again. If you plunge by pulling _up_ you'll eventually pull the clog out of the drain pipe and you can pick it up and throw it in the garbage. This will leave your drain (mostly) clear of the clog and you can go on your merry way for months/years (depending on hair shed factor of shower users) until hair & soap build up again.